# is it possible to monitor more than one stream simultanously?

Tags: perl

E.g.
- $stream1 is the STDOUT of a child process and $stream2 is the STDERR of the same child process
- $stream1 is one child process and $stream2 is another child process

Is there a possiblility in perl to monitor two or more streams at the same time?

So we loop as long as anything pops-up in any of the streams and we take whatever comes first either in $stream1 or $stream2.

Something like

```
while (my $line = <$stream1 or $stream2> ) {  
    #do something with the $line
}
```

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is - it's Perl, after all - just not with *quite* such an elegant syntax.

Monitoring several streams boils down to judicious use of the `select` syscall, and in Perl that means using the four-argument version of [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html#select-RBITS%2cWBITS%2cEBITS%2cTIMEOUT), which wraps this syscall. Many people find this a bit too cumbersome and low-level, so of course there is a [module](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch17_20.htm) which further wraps the pattern for your convenience.